# Пример создания блокнота не работает

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, макросы, печать

Пытаюсь запустить пример создания блокнота из туториалов Qt (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-notepad-example.html) без QtCreator.

В конструкторе

```
Notepad::Notepad(QWidget* parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::Notepad) {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setCentralWidget(ui->textEdit);

    connect(ui->actionNew, &QAction::triggered, this, &Notepad::newDocument);
    connect(ui->actionOpen, &QAction::triggered, this, &Notepad::open);
    connect(ui->actionSave, &QAction::triggered, this, &Notepad::save);
    connect(ui->actionSave_as, &QAction::triggered, this, &Notepad::saveAs);
    connect(ui->actionPrint, &QAction::triggered, this, &Notepad::print);
    connect(ui->actionExit, &QAction::triggered, this, &Notepad::exit);
    connect(ui->actionCopy, &QAction::triggered, this, &Notepad::copy);
    connect(ui->actionCut, &QAction::triggered, this, &Notepad::cut);
    connect(ui->actionPaste, &QAction::triggered, this, &Notepad::paste);
    connect(ui->actionUndo, &QAction::triggered, this, &Notepad::undo);
    connect(ui->actionRedo, &QAction::triggered, this, &Notepad::redo);
    connect(ui->actionFont, &QAction::triggered, this, &Notepad::selectFont);
    connect(ui->actionBold, &QAction::triggered, this, &Notepad::setFontBold);
    connect(ui->actionUnderline, &QAction::triggered, this, &Notepad::setFontUnderline);
    connect(ui->actionItalic, &QAction::triggered, this, &Notepad::setFontItalic);
    connect(ui->actionAbout, &QAction::triggered, this, &Notepad::about);

// Disable menu actions for unavailable features
#if !QT_CONFIG(printer)
    ui->actionPrint->setEnabled(false);
#endif

#if !QT_CONFIG(clipboard)
    ui->actionCut->setEnabled(false);
    ui->actionCopy->setEnabled(false);
    ui->actionPaste->setEnabled(false);
#endif
}
```

в макросе

```
// Disable menu actions for unavailable features
#if !QT_CONFIG(printer)
    ui->actionPrint->setEnabled(false);
#endif
```

получаю

> error: division by zero in #if !QT_CONFIG(printer)

Судя по всему, это связано с тем, что следующая цепочка включений не срабатывает

```
#if defined(QT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB)
#include <QtPrintSupport/qtprintsupportglobal.h>
#if QT_CONFIG(printer)
#if QT_CONFIG(printdialog)
#include <QPrintDialog>
#endif // QT_CONFIG(printdialog)
#include <QPrinter>
#endif // QT_CONFIG(printer)
#endif // QT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB
```

Как можно исправить пример, чтобы работало без установки библиотеки для печати (QT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB)?

Comment: А ошибку вы получаете когда?

Answer (score 0):

В файле [notepad.pro](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-notepad-notepad-pro.html) нужно закоментировать строчку где добавляется модуль `QPrintSupport`, вот так:

```
# qtHaveModule(printsupport): QT += printsupport
```

После этого макрос `#if defined (QT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB)` перестанет выполнятся и все что связано с печатью отключится. Это если вы ничего в примере не меняли конечно.